# Pattern/idiom for clean nested State Machines?

Tags: ruby, oop, design-patterns, state-machine

I'm trying to figure out a nice clean ruby/oo way to solve a problem of nested state machines.

I'm modelling a system that takes orders. Orders are implemented as a state machine with various changes in flow depending on whether it is residential/commercial, qc/no-qc, foreign/domestic.

I'm coming up empty on a good way to design this. A new class with its own workflow for each combination of options works, but is very not-DRY, and branches quite quickly with additional options.

I'm trying to figure out if there is a way to build this up via composition, where an Order would defer/delegate into its appropriate sub workflow states at each branch based on the previously mention residential/commercial/etc and then come back to the main order flow when that is complete.

There doesn't seem to be a way to do it with the workflow gem that I'm using, and none of the other state machine implementations I've looked at support it.

Is there perhaps a very ruby approach that would allow me to delegate depending on internal state? Is there a general OO pattern that might work well here? Am I approaching this an odd way?

Comment: _Delegate depending on internal state_ makes me think [State Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/State_pattern).

Comment: Hard to say without seeing more of the problem. If most of the differences between workflows were simple do-this-or-don't-do-this decisions, you might be able to write a small number of Strategy classes to handle the complex difference and parameterize them to handle the simple options. If it was more complex you might want to combine steps in a DSL, something I've seen before in commercial workflow software.

Answer (score -1):

Because Ruby is very similiar to Python you can have a look at this [python implementation of a nested state machine](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/hsm.py) which uses the state pattern. The state machine (a message handler) changes its super states (in service / out of service) and inheriting states (active, standby / suspect, failed) based on a single event "source" (the message type). The python implementation is a port of a C++ example. You can find the class diagram and explanation of the C++ example [here](http://www.eventhelix.com/RealtimeMantra/HierarchicalStateMachine.htm#.V0V0BEL950x).

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please [add context around the link](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/169503) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline. Take into account that being _barely more than a link to an external site_ is a possible reason as to [Why and how are some answers deleted?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Comment: You are totally right. But i am no friend of duplication and i do not know what additional information would be helpful to answer the question in more detail (as there is not more detail included in the question itself). For me it is ok to delete this answer. However it would also delete the only hint right now to a possible solution...